# Retrieve data from second table when there is no column relations

Tags: php, mysql, regex

**I need a query to retrieve all shops that are related to specifif "industry"**

My mate designed table without foreign key and as many to many relation, he used Regex when separating with ","

> **TABLE shops**
>
> **id | phone | address | type**
>
> 1 | 11111     | XXXXX | ,10,12,13
>
> 3 | 22121     | XXXXX | ,33,37,38
>
> 5 | 11111     | XXXXX | ,51,52,55
>
> **TABLE types**
>
> **ID |    industry |  type**
>
> 10 |  service  |  taxi
>
> 12 |  service  |  delivery
>
> 13 |  service  |  mail
>
> 33 |  primary  |  electriticy
>
> 37 |  primary  |  water
>
> 38 |  primary  |  gas
>
> 51 |  edu      |  primary school
>
> 52 |  edu      |  high school
>
> 55 |  edu      |  university
>
> 60...
>   70...

Is there any possibility to retrieve like ex: with WHERE types.industry = 'service' in a single query?

I'm having trouble to do it, though all about Joins or Subqueries etc, but i came up with no solution.

Looking for help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding correctly, one option is to `join` using  `find_in_set()`:

```
select *
from shops s
  join types t on find_in_set(t.id, s.type)
where t.industry = 'service'
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e1f36/2)